# Sentence with と 来ている！

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

I started watching Hi score girl, and in the first episode there is a sentence like this :
コイツはこんな所に来る 女の子ではなかったはず
成績優秀で誰からも慕われ―
しかも金持ちの娘と 来ている！

I've never seen と 来ている！
Is this a mistake in subtitles or some grammar that i don't understand ? what does this last sentence mean mean ?